# Swift - unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when adding item to array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array like so:

```
var gestureArray: Array<UIGestureRecognizer>!
```

and I am trying to add item to this array like so:

```
for gesture in webview.scrollView.gestureRecognizers!
        {
            gestureArray.insert(gesture, atIndex: 0)
        }

        print(gestureArray)
```

but I get this error after attempting to add the first item:

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

When I print each gesture they look like this:

```
<UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer: 0x124eabb60; state = Possible; delaysTouchesBegan = YES; view = <_UIWebViewScrollView 0x125825400>; target= <(action=delayed:, target=<_UIWebViewScrollView 0x125825400>)>>

<UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer: 0x124eac370; state = Possible; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <_UIWebViewScrollView 0x125825400>; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=<_UIWebViewScrollView 0x125825400>)>>

<UIScrollViewPinchGestureRecognizer: 0x124d892a0; state = Possible; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <_UIWebViewScrollView 0x125825400>; target= <(action=handlePinch:, target=<_UIWebViewScrollView 0x125825400>)>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that the array has not been initialized to a non-nil value.

When you put exclamation point `!` after a type, you tell Swift two things:

- It is perfectly legal for the value of `gestureArray` to be `nil`, and
- You are going to assign a non-nil value to `gestureArray` prior to accessing it.

In return Swift lets you access `gestureArray` as if it were not optional (i.e. with `gestureArray.insert(...)` instead of `gestureArray!.insert(...)`)

From the exception that you are getting it appears that `gestureArray` is still `nil` when you call `insert` on it.

Comment: Can u give me an example of what I should do?

Comment: @user979331 Depending on your requirements you could make `gestureArray` non-optional, i.e. `var gestureArray = [UIGestureRecognizer]()` or add a line to initialize it, if you would like to keep it optional.

Answer (score 2):

Your `gestureArray` value is nil. You can create the variable this way:

`var gestureArray = [UIGestureRecognizer]()`

You were creating a variable and setting its type, but its value was never assigned. And there is another error, and it's that you cannot create a class property and set it as an `unwrapped optional`. You should always or create a variable and assign it a value, or set its type as `optional`. Ex: `var gestureArray: [UIGestureRecognizer]?`